# I simply want to be able to programmatically change the audio of a video to use headphones and not hdmi. Is this possible?

Tags: audio-playback

I tried

```
amixer cset numid=3 1
```

but I get

```
amixer: Cannot find the given element from control default
```

I tested the headphones with

```
speaker-test -t sine -f 440 -c 2 -s 1
```

and hear the sound through the headphones and not the tv so I know the hardware works.

But I want the mp4 video I'm playing to redirect the sound to headphones not tv

Comment: Have a look at pulseaudio.